# How to set up a trigger that works as similar as onEdit trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script

I was trying to make onEdit trigger for my spreadsheet which triggers when the values in specific range changes. but I heard that onEdit trigger doesn't work when the changes were made by automatically through script.

I heard form submission trigger is one of the solutions, so I had a bit of research but I still could not get the idea. Can someone teach me how to use form submission trigger or is there other method to replace onEdit trigger?

Comment: Hi! Please, clarify if you are the one in control of the script that updates the spreadsheet?

Comment: Are you hoping to run a script when someone submits a form?

Comment: @OlegValter Yes I am in control of the script, and me and my co-worker updates data in spreadsheet.

Comment: @J.G. my goal is to run a script when values in a certain sheet and column changes even if the values were edited through script.

Comment: Why don't you leave the `onEdit` be and add a value change check at the end of the script that performs changes to the spreadheet - this way you will have both the capability for triggering callback on explicit cell edit and via the script?

Comment: @Oleg Valter Thank you for a nice and simple solution!

Comment: Don't mention! Btw, I encountered a question similar to yours before that [deals with spreadsheet change latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402123/google-sheets-calulation-latency-and-dependant-function-calls/56403373#56403373) - take a look at the answer if you ever encounter such a problem