# google sheets calulation latency and dependant function calls

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, async-await, google-sheets-formula, calculation

Here is a function that pupulates a column with a formula:

```
function fillAccount(lastRow) {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(' ');
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate()
  .setFormula('=ifna(vlookup(C2,Accounts!$A$1:$A$7,1,false),B1)');
  spreadsheet.getRange('B3').activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B3:B' + lastRow).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
}
```

There is some latency from the time this function completes and all of the rows in column B are populated with the results of the calculation.  I want to execute another function after this one but that function need to have all rows populated before it can execute.  Here is how it would appear in driver script:

```
fillAccount(lastrow);
copyAllData(); // this needs to have all rows in column B fully 
               // populated.
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your function needs a bit of cleanup (it can be done refined further, but that's a start):

```
function fillAccount(lastRow) {
  var spreadsheet = getSpread(); //custom method calling the Spreadsheet, change to your logic;

  var colB = spreadsheet.getRange('B1:B'+lastRow);
  var row1 = colB.getCell(1,1);
  var row2 = colB.getCell(2,1);      

  row1.setValue(' ');
  row2.setFormula('=ifna(vlookup(C2,RENAMED!$A$1:$A$7,1,false),B1)');
  row2.copyTo(colB.offset(1,0,lastRow-1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //make sure changes are applied;      
}
```

Then, simply call the second function and make sure you access values to ensure calculation (if you have a pretty long latency (e.g. > 1s for each formula calc), some formulas might end up with `#ERROR!` value - if you want to account for that, add check `==='#ERROR!'` that terminates second function upon encountering such a value and recursively restarts it):

```
/**
 * Caller function;
 */
function triggerFill() {

  //...your logic and lastRow initialization here;

  fillAccount(lastRow);
  copyAllData();
}

/**
 * Function accessing updated values;
 */
function copyAllData() {
  var spreadsheet = getSpread(); //custom method calling the Spreadsheet, change to your logic;
  var dataRange = spreadsheet.getDataRange(); //just an example that gets all data;
  var values = dataRange.getValues(); //just an example that gets all values;
  for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    if(values[i].indexOf('#ERROR!')!==-1) { //for high latency;
      Utilities.sleep(t) //change t to number of ms to wait to your liking;
      return copyAllData();
    }
  }

  //do other stuff, like cell copy;
}
```