# Problem with trigger 'On change' running continuously while source of data spreadsheet is updating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet (Data_Collect_API) that collects data from an API and it's quite an extensive function.
I then have another spreadsheet (Data_Stats) that =IMPORTRANGE from (Data_Collect_API).
The spreadsheet (Data_Stats) copies some data around etc. (function is triggered by On change) after =IMPORTRANGE have changed (thus there was new data on source spreadsheet).

The problem I'm facing is that source spreadsheet (Data_Collect_API) is updating with data from API, and then the destination spreadsheet (Data_Stats) IMPORTRANGE updates a sheet, triggering the On change and then running a function. This is all good... but, the Data_Stats spreadsheets On change gets triggered multiple times while Data_Collect_API is still busy running it's function.

So question is how can I make sure that Data_Stats sheet function triggered by On change only happens once after the Data_Collect_API has been updated?

Hope my question makes sense...

Comment: I thought of maybe using Utilities.sleep in the Data_Stats spreadsheet's function, with the idea that it gives enough time for Data_Collect_API's function to complete,  but not sure if it's a good idea...

Comment: Have you tried using `LockService`?

Comment: Your question makes sense, the best thing you can do, in my opinion, is to stop using `=IMPORTRANGE` since you already use apps script as the code-based solution and update the target Sheet via `copyTo()` or anything Range-related instead + add your target function call at the end of copy function. Regarding latency and calling second function, there was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402123/google-sheets-calulation-latency-and-dependant-function-calls/56403373#56403373) recently

Comment: @Altigraph yes I've read that some are using LockService as a possible solution...

Comment: @OlegValter =IMPORTRANGE might just be the part that is really the issue as you suggest. I thought this way I could avoid more time spent with App Script and limitations... But Let me rather try as you suggest will update here when done.

Comment: That's the usual stuff - better control means more scripting. I think your situation here warrants a code-based approach, though as you'll have latency control as well as ensuring that the function is run only one. Let me know if you succeed or you encounter any issues!

Comment: @OlegValter you were correct, getting rid of =IMPORTRANGE and substituting code based solution from source spreadsheet solved my issue

Comment: @Petrus - glad to hear :) In my opinion, when you start using code-based solutions, formulas become kind of obsolete.